# For loop through a char array jumping out of the loop on first iteration - Android/Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

So I've discovered some really bizarre behavior going through some older code in my Android app. I found a method for validating whether or not a string is digits only that looks like this:

```
public static boolean isDigitsOnly(String value) {
    char[] chars = value.toCharArray();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Say you passed in "410ABC". This looks like it should loop through 4, 1, and 0, get to A and then hit the false and return. That is not the case I've observed, it gets right to the if statement and immediately jumps out to the return true. I was beginning to think it might be my machine and the JVM got confused. I restarted, still did it. I tried it on 2 different machines as well, my work laptop and home desktop, exact same behavior. I loaded up Intellij to try on a standard java project and to my surprise it worked just fine! By now my mind is beyond blown and I decided not to waste anymore time and refactored it into:

```
public static boolean isDigitsOnly(String value) {
    return value.length() > 0 && value.matches("[0-9]+");
}
```

Works just fine, this is the better solution anyway but I can't help but wonder what in the world is going on with the first method. Anyone got any ideas on why it acts like this? This might keep me up at night until it is solved!

Comment: Go into debug mode, and inspect what `chars` is before entering the loop. Does it have the expected length? Also, I don't really see the point in using `char[]` when you could do `string.charAt(i)` with a regular for loop. But for the sake of argument, let's just stick with this.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, and it works for me. Just as @Vucko suggested, go into debug mode, and look for the `value` you're passing to your method, it may not be what you expect.

Comment: Is it possible that isDigit() is treating A, B, C as hexidecimal?

Comment: @ja08prat That actually does sound legit!

Comment: It shows **{4, 1, 0 , A, B, C }**. The value passed in is actually passing a string.isempty() check as well before the method is called. I don't like the iterative approach so I'm sticking with the regex for now.

Comment: It depends probably on the encoding, I have tested it in UTF, ISO8859-1 and windows-1252 and it works just fine.

Comment: interesting. I just cut-n-pasted your stuff. It worked as expected. Java 1.8_112.

Comment: So I wrote up some unit tests for our isDigitsOnly() and its working for me. However when debugging, the current line highlight is what is throwing this off. When the if statment reaches a character that fails, the current line indicator of the debugger jumps down to the return true statement but it actually still returns false like it should. Once I got this in isolation I realized there was another bug causing the overall validation to fail. It was just this misleading jump of the debugger line that made it look like it was this method failing.